# Concatenating addres fields in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sfdc

I have sample data with following address fields,

| billing_address | billing_city | billing_state | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 216 Street, Suite. A | Lynwood | Washington | USA |

The goal is to get the address in following format;

**Expected Output**

```
12345 216 Street, Suite A
 Lynwood, Washington
 USA
```

here is my sql code for it;

```
select billing_address & BR()
   & billing_city & ", "
   & billing_state & BR()
   & billing_country
from temp_data
```

I am getting the following error;

```
Error: invalid identifier '", "'
```

Can I kindly get some help on how to fix it? thanks

Comment: Your text delimiter possibly needs to be single-quote - ie. ' - not double-quote?

Comment: double quotes is an identifier token (aka table name, column name) and single quotes are strings (is Snowflake SQL) but thoise `&` are not valid SQL so perhaps this is not running in snowflake, albeit that looks like a Snowflake error message

Answer (score 0):

so it seems a mix of pre-processor and SQL:

```
select 
    '12345 216 Street, Suite. A' as billing_address,
    'Lynwood' as billing_city,
    'Washington' as billing_state,
    'USA' as billing_country,
    billing_address || BR()|| billing_city || ", " || billing_state || BR() || billing_country
```

but almost as it stand it does give the error you note:

[image]

changing to just Snowflake SQL:

```
select 
    '12345 216 Street, Suite. A' as billing_address,
    'Lynwood' as billing_city,
    'Washington' as billing_state,
    'USA' as billing_country,
    billing_address || '\r\n' || billing_city || ', ' || billing_state || '\r\n' || billing_country;
```

[image]